# Spring data jpa - Why the generated SQL contains unkown columns which is not even in Entity fields?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am following [this blog by Vlad](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) to implement One-To-One relation in b/w my two entities `User` and `JobProfile`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer userId;

    @Column(name = "unique_id", unique = true, length = 45, updatable = false)
    private String uniqueId;

    @Column(name = "email", unique = true, length = 45, updatable = false)
    private String email;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "job_profile")
public class JobProfile  {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "is_looking_job")
    private Boolean isLookingJob;


}
```

Idea is, my client will send job details for a user. The data(i have reduced for simplicity) would be like:
{
  "isLookingJob": true
}

The controller would be responsible for the creation of `JobProfile` for the user.

```
public void saveUserExperience(Principal principal, @RequestBody UserExperienceDto experienceDto) {
        User user = userService.findByEmail(principal.getName());       

        JobProfile jobProfile = new JobProfile();
        jobProfile.setUser(user);

        JobHistory jobHistory = new JobHistory();
        jobHistory.setIsLookingJob(experienceDto.getIsWilling())

        jobProfileDao.save(jobProfile);


    }
```

`JobProfileDao` is a Spring-Data-Jpa interface.

```
public interface JobProfileDao extends JpaRepository<JobProfile, Integer> {

}
```

So, the save operation here is generating the wrong SQL command(`insert into job_profile (is_looking_job, is_willing, user_user_id) values (?, ?, ?)`) and hence giving the error `could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement`

I am quite confused to see that from where `user_user_id` column  got generated.

I am using Spring boot with Spring-data-Jpa + Hibernate  for my project.

Comment: Perhaps because you have `OneToOne` relation with `User` table as `user`. And `User` table has `user_id`, so it makes `user_user_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `@JoinColumn` on `JobProfile.user` field, and therefore hibernate uses `user_user_id` (based on field name and name of PK column in `User`)

In fact, [the article you mention](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) has the following note

> If you want to customize the Primary Key column name when using @MapsId, you need to use the @JoinColumn annotation. For more details, check out this article.

[How to change the @OneToOne shared primary key column name with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/change-one-to-one-primary-key-column-jpa-hibernate/)

Comment: shit man, how did I skip the last part of the article. Thanks @Lesiak